# Windows 10 1809 - Office 365 start menu search not working?

Tags: windows-10, office365, start-menu

I have an issue on clients on Windows 10 1809 when searching for Excel for example it does not show in the search results. Or any other office 365 application. If I logon to a different profile it works? Since I don't want to recreate profiles for every user is there another solution for this?

Comment: There should not be so many broken profiles. For one computer: uninstall Office completely (and any old versions that may still exist). Restart, Install just Office 365 and patch fully.  Open Indexing Options, make sure Locations include USERS, Outlook and any other location you need. Restart after changes, rebuild the index and see if the problem appears to be corrected

Comment: It seems the issue is that the shortcuts here C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs are not searchable?